# Using overlapped structure for callback?

Tags: c++, windows, asynchronous, overlapped-io, io-completion-ports

I have my own overlapped structure for asynchronous IO using IO Completion ports.

Now i get notification for read / write completions. Can i pass a CALLBACK function as a parameter in the overlapped structure?

This will allow me to specify various callback functions based on the type of overlapped structure i passed

Has anybody had any luck with this?

Comment: The overlapped structure is *almost* always extended to include implementation-defined data. I see no reason why you couldn't stuff a callback function pointer in there as well. Note however that GetQueueCompeletionStatus loops are often complex enough, and pushing the underlying data through to a CB may not buy you much (but I can certainly see how it could eliminate a `switch` or jump-table dereference from the loop).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create you own structure derived from `OVERLAPPED`:

```
struct MyOverlapped : OVERLAPPED
{
  CALLBACK MyCallback;
};
```

Now use this instead:

```
MyOverlapped *o=new MyOverlapped;
o->MyCallback=CallbackHandler;

WriteFile(..,..,MyOverlapped);
```

Then when you get the `OVERLAPPED` back you can cast it to your derived version:

```
MyOverlapped *o=static_cast<MyOverlapped*>(overlapped);
```

And now you can access the callback. I'm guessing you're getting the `OVERLAPPED` instance back from a call to `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` where the pointer you get back will actually point to your derived structure.